# How to get the length of a div in angularjs on click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

This is really basic but I don't know why I'm not able to solve this problem.

I'm trying to get the length of a div when I click on it, I've tried different ways to do that but with no success at all.

Here is an example of what I want: http://plnkr.co/edit/eGqu2HSUixr0S5CH3jNr?p=preview

If someone can explain how is the 'angular way' to do that will be really appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` will refer to the `scope`, try passing `$event.target` instead, and
wrap it with `angular.element` because you want to call `html()`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ibBNM0wK4RDH2JnamfV9?p=preview

```
<div ng-click="getLength($event.target)">Click to know the length of this string</div>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $parse) {
  $scope.getLength = function(obj) {
    var obj = angular.element(obj);
    try {
      $scope.output = (obj !== undefined) ? obj.html().length : 'undefined';
    } catch(err) {
      $scope.output = err.message;
    }

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to know the length of a string in the DOM, then the Angular way of doing it would be to put the functionality in a custom directive.

```
app.directive('sendLengthOnClick', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      'localSendLength': '&sendLengthOnClick'
    },
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttr) {
      iElement.on('click', function() {
        var length = iElement.text().length;
        scope.localSendLength({length:length});
      });
    }
  }
});
```

You can then add the attribute `send-length-on-click` on any element, to send the string length to a function on the parent scope:

```
<div send-length-on-click="useLength(length)">Click to know the length of this string</div>
```

You can see this in action in the following Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Zuk2wnndayvBgYyNXQaL?p=preview

However, I would be curious to know why you would like this. It feels a bit close to calculations based on model data, which would be more usual to be in a service, fetching the length of the string before it hits the DOM, rather than after.

Comment: True! Unfortunately, I come from a jQuery world, used to do a lot of DOM manipulations. I'm working to change the way I think when I'm using Angular, so any best practices or advices to change my process of thinking will be highly appreciated. I just created a custom email component. This component to be as functional as an input, I'm obliged to deal with these kind of manipulations, anyways if you can shed some light on this to do it in the right Angular way, would be awesome! You can check this component here: http://plnkr.co/edit/9TmCt2vWzdOgWtrBIkEZ?p=preview

Comment: Not completely related to the original question, but at the moment I think a choice of a div with contenteditable="true" to be overcomplicating it, and would be quite difficult to get right, in terms of making sure the user doesn't break it (what if the user hits enter, or pastes some html in there?). Standard HTML already has the `placeholder` attribute on `<input>`, and ng-model on an `<input>` element can tie it to a value on a scope. If you need some custom validation, then you should read up on [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController)